# Printing out Category and all Category Children on category.php

Tags: categories

A new site i'm making is going to use extensive use of the categories, so here's what i'm trying to accomplish:

Main Category Name (Link)

List of Sub Categories (All Links)

When i'm on a sub-category page I want it to look like the Main Category page just with the sub-categories highlited.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's damn simple, see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories .
The sample downhere should work:

```
$kids = get_categories(array('child_of'=>get_query_var('cat')));
```